Вопрос по фамилии "Сапыш" (ударение на А)
Известно, что женская фамилия не склоняется - с Анной Сапыш.
Мужская склоняется - с Иваном Сапышем.
Надо ли склонять, когда речь идёт о паре? Например,
Почему не пригласили Анну и Ивана Сапышей (или Сапыш)?
Почему не пригласили Ивана и Анну Сапыш (или Сапышей)?
В семье Сапыш (или Сапышей?) всё хорошо.

Если речь идёт о паре, то
читайте мой ответ - там подробнее, чем смогла вместить картинка.

Почему не пригласили Анну и Ивана Сапыш?
Почему не пригласили Ивана и Анну Сапыш?
В семье Сапыш всё хорошо.

Розенталь, §151.

7) при слове "семья" фамилия обычно ставится в форме единственного числа, например: семья Оппенгейм, семья Гофмансталь.

